# Fetch Tag Name from Tag ID | Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to fetch the TAG Name with Tag ID, I tried it using get_tag() function but it doesn't print anything.

```
<?php
$certification = get_tag(13);
echo $certification->name; ?>
```

As I checked there is a Tag available in my wordpress with ID 13

can someone help to fix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code -

```
$tag_id = get_term_by('id', 13, 'post_tag');
echo $tag_id->name;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I checked again the tag ID is correct.

Comment: I have modified the code, can you please try the new code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$post_tags = get_the_tags($id); //your tagid
if ( $post_tags ) {
    echo $post_tags[0]->name; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for getting the term name by id

```
$term = get_term( 13, 'post_tag' );
echo $term->name;
```

Hope it will work as I have tried it and working perfectly.